# Apache Flink: map vs flatMap

Tags: apache-flink

In flink, flatMap can also emit one record. It seems flatMap can replace map. Can somebody tell me the differrence in this situation? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are thinking that map is superfluous, you are correct. Flatmap can do everything map can do, and more.

Nevertheless, I do use map in situations where there is a strict one-to-one correspondence between input and output. This serves as a clear indication to the reader that, for example, there are no situations where errors or invalid input would cause the operation to fail to produce an output record.

Comment: Thanks very much! For me, it is better to use flatMap. Because I will present a unified port to users in my company. Less is simple.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between `map` and `flatMap` is the return type. 
Both methods work on DataStream and DataSet objects and executed for each element in the stream or the set.

However, the `map` method returns exactly one element, whereas the `flatMap`  returns a collection (which can hold none, one, or more elements).

- The `map` method receives an argument of the interface `MapFunction` with the method `O out map(I elem)`. The input is an element, the output is one object.
- The `flatMap` method receives an argument of the interface `FlatMapFunction` with the method `void  flatMap(I elem, Collector<O> out)`. The input is an element, the output is a collection of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map()` also makes it easy to use lambdas. For example, to convert a `Tuple2<Integer, String>` to just the `String`, you can do.

```
.map(value -> value.f1)
```